# trouble starting environment server for arm_navigation stack

Tags: ros, ros-electric, planning-environment, arm-navigation, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with the new electric arm_navigation stack. I went through the wizard and am working with my auto generated launch and config files. So when I launch my arm_navigation launch file, everything seems fine except it continues to get hung up on:

```
[ INFO] : waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] : Robot frame is base_link
[ INFO] : Waiting for robot state ...
[ INFO] : Waiting for joint state ...
[ WARN] : Got joint state update but did not update some joints for more than 1 second.  Turn on DEBUG for more info
[ INFO] : Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] : waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] : Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] : waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] : Waiting for robot state ...
[ INFO] : Waiting for joint state ...
```

....If I don't include the environment server by commenting the following out of my launch file....

```
<include file="$(find planning_environment)/launch/environment_server.launch">
    <arg name="use_monitor" value="true" />
    <arg name="use_collision_map" value="false" />
</include>
```

....then it stops complaining. But of course if I don't include the environment server then I can't run any of my clients to move the arm.

I've already found this [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/2591/constraint_aware_simple_arm_server-hanging-on) but I'm already doing a fake publisher and the problem persists even when I don't include the joints I'm having to fake publish.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before or do I seem to be forgetting a small but cruicial step in getting this to launch?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11695/trouble-starting-environment-server-for-arm_navigation-stack/) by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After going back into my fake joint publisher, I had missed a couple of joints. That was the fix. Launching no longer gets hung up on the environment server.

If you need help with this topic similar to mine, use this script: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm/file/5b219f3e6b8e/turtlebot_arm_bringup/scripts/fake_pub.py to do a fake publish joints that normally don't have a transform. Just be sure to verify you included all of your joints (my mistake).

---

Originally posted by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) with karma: 178 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on 2012-04-13**:
Hi seth, I'm having trouble similar to what you posted here, but I don't have much experience with ROS or linux, and I don't know what should I put instead of: "roslib.load_manifest("turtlebot_arm_bringup")" in the fake_publisher script, if I'm working too with my own robot. Thanks!

**Comment by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on 2012-06-15**:
Carlos, replace "turtlebot_arm_bringup" with the package name that you are working in. for more details, look here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown